# How are differential forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ independent of coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, differential-forms

I am currently learning about differential forms in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A certain phrase keeps popping up: "differential forms are an approach to multivariable calculus that is independent of coordinates." I have a few questions about this:

1. When we write out the basis one-forms $dx_1, \dots, dx_n$ on $\mathbb{R^n}$, we do so with respect to the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Even how they are defined: $$ dx_i ( [ v_1 \dots v_n ] ) = v_i, $$ is in terms of the standard basis. **How is this independent of coordinates? Is there a way to specify the same differential forms without choosing a basis?**
2. **How is it useful that differential forms are independent of coordinates?** From the calculations I've done with differential forms so far, all of them have been in terms of the basis 1-forms $dx_i$ mentioned above. Do we ever have to do calculations abstractly without coordinates? Or is the "independence of coordinates" more of a philosophical requirement, and if so, how does it arise?

Thanks for the help! Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should add a precise quote since the expression "differential forms are independent of coordinates" by itself is not sufficiently informative. For instance, it can mean that the definition of differential forms is independent of the choice of coordinates or that some proofs are...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made some changes - hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing about $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that it "naturally" comes with a choice of coordinates since $\mathbb{R}^n = \overbrace{\mathbb{R}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}}^n$ this means that elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are of the form $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)$. We also have maps

\begin{align*}
x_i &=\text{pr}_i : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
&\mathbf{x} \mapsto x_i
\end{align*}

These maps are also natural and they do not need the introduction of more objects. And the basis one forms are the differentials of these maps, so technically we haven't chosen coordinates we've only used the definition of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can use different coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^n$ though, say for the case $n=2$ we can use polar coordinates (though there is a slight subtlety at the origin). In this case we have the basis forms $dr$ and $d\varphi$, and if we use the rule of how differential forms change under change of coordinate $ (r,\varphi)\mapsto (x,y)$ we find

$$dx=\cos\varphi dr - r \sin \varphi d\varphi  \hspace{15mm}  dy = \sin\varphi dr + r \cos \varphi d\varphi$$

From here we notice that $dx\wedge dy = r dr \wedge d\varphi$ (*technically I should have written pullbacks but that's beside the point*). We see that we obtain the element of area in polar, so the area of a region given in polar coordinates is the same as it would have been if I used cartesian. This is the reason why coordinate independence is useful because I can define an object $\omega = dx\wedge dy$ in cartesian, and write an expression like

$$\int_D \omega =\text{Area}(D)$$

And that expression does not depend on whether I use polar or cartesian coordinates.

A lot of the definitions can be made into coordinate independent ones, some of them are not as popular as the coordinate versions though. For example you have probably seen the definition for the exterior derivative of a one form $\alpha= \alpha_j dx^j$ in local coordinates as

$$d\alpha = d\alpha_j \wedge dx^j = \partial_i \alpha_j dx^i \wedge dx^j$$

There is however a coordinate independent definition for the exterior derivative, the one for one forms becomes

$$d\alpha(X,Y) = X(\alpha(Y))- Y(\alpha(X))- \alpha(\left[X,Y\right])$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your thorough response. 

As a follow up to your comment about polar vs. cartesian coordinates, I'm wondering whether it's even necessary to introduce forms here? I.e: couldn't we still say $\int dx \, dy = \int r \, dr \, d \theta$, and say that $dx \, dy$ describes a "coordinate-free object" using Cartesian coordinates, which can then be transformed to other coordinate systems? Is the main benefit of differential forms that they make rigorous the idea of "$dx \, dy$" as an object? Or is there a deeper meaning beyond just rigor?

Comment: Yes they are a way of generalizing integration such that when changing coordinates the n-forms pick up the Jacobian of the transformation which is the correct factor to leave the integral invariant under change of coordinates. Also it is useful to do things coordinate free since if you're describing a general manifold, you don't have global coordinates so you are forced to use local coordinates or coordinate independent definitions. If you use the local coordinates you have to check that everything is compatible under changes of coordinates.

Comment: I see - thanks a lot! That really helps.